# Changing Stripe currency from default USD to GBP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I think I have changed the parts of my code necessary to use GBP rather than USD.  However, whilst the correct figures are displaying in my Stripe card charging modal the 'charge' button still displays USD.

My current view:

```
    <%= link_to 'Enroll', course_enrollments_path(@course), class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :post %>
    <%= form_tag course_enrollments_path(@course) do %>

    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
            data-description="A month's subscription"
            data-amount="<%= (@course.cost * 100).to_i %>"></script>
    <% end %>
```

My current controller:

```
def create
    current_user.enrollments.create(course: current_course)

    # Amount in pence
    @amount = (current_course.cost * 100).to_i

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => current_user.email,
      :card  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Flixter Enrollment',
      :currency    => 'gbp'
    )

    redirect_to course_path(current_course)

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to root_path
    end
```

Apologies, if I haven't given enough information or my terminology is wrong - I am new to coding and StackOverflow :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You ned to add the currency to Stripe Checkout as below

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
        data-description="A month's subscription"
        data-amount="<%= (@course.cost * 100).to_i %>"
        data-currency="GBP"
        ></script>
```

Comment: Hi Matt - this doesn't seem to to work.  I think the > before the closing script tag is erroneous(?) but even without that its makes no difference.  No error is given just that USD is still used.

Comment: I'd double check that the data-currency is actually being rendered, it should work per https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

Comment: You may also need to change the currency in your charge call